# How to access the main GUI thread from within a SWITCH statement?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, switch-statement

I need to update the BG colour of a button from a delegate function, but when I try to access the main thread from inside the switch statement I get compiler errors.

Code as below

```
switch (peripheral.state) {
        case CBManagerStatePoweredOn:
            NSLog(@"Powered on");
            [peripheral startAdvertising:_beaconPeripheralData];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                _adminPageExitBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            });
            break;
        case CBManagerStatePoweredOff:
            NSLog(@"Powered Off");
            [peripheral stopAdvertising];
            break;
        case CBManagerStateUnsupported:
            NSLog(@"Device not supported");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

The error message is as follows

```
/Users/mdouhan/Documents/Documents - Mattias’s MacBook/NWMobileTill/NWMobileTill/AdminView.m:161:9: Cannot jump from switch statement to this case label
/Users/mdouhan/Documents/Documents - Mattias’s MacBook/NWMobileTill/NWMobileTill/AdminView.m:150:55: Jump enters lifetime of block which strongly captures a variable
```

How do I correctly update the BG colour of my button from that delegate method?

Comment: Try wrapping the case in curly brackets. I've had issues before where you have to explicitly define the scope. Ex: `case CBManagerStatePoweredOn: { /* code and block here */ } break;`

Comment: That removes the error messages but the button don't change colour but the debug shows me that CASE is hit

Comment: And you're positive that the button is properly hooked up? If you try to change the button color elsewhere on the main thread, it works?

Comment: I can see it go green for a second when I click it and it closes that UIController, so it seems to be a timing/thread issue

Comment: its defined like this in the header @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *adminPageExitBtn;

Comment: What's the context that this switch statement is called in? Is it possible that the delegate (which I'm assuming is a VC) is subsequently setting the background color soon afterwards?

Comment: It is called and it is starting to broadcast and I see the powered On debug statement

Answer (score 1):

Scope in case statements is weird, by the definition of the C spec.

Or, more specifically, case statements do not define a scope.  The scope is defined by the switch() {...} itself and the cases are really just standard labels where the switch does a goto style jump to the correct label.   The way a block declaration works causes interference with the jump behavior of the switch.

The cleanest fix is to simply ensure that every case has a unique scope:

```
switch (peripheral.state) {
        case CBManagerStatePoweredOn:
        {
            NSLog(@"Powered on");
            [peripheral startAdvertising:_beaconPeripheralData];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                _adminPageExitBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            });
        }
            break;
        case CBManagerStatePoweredOff:
        {
            NSLog(@"Powered Off");
            [peripheral stopAdvertising];
        }
            break;
        case CBManagerStateUnsupported:
        {
            NSLog(@"Device not supported");
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Or, alternatively, just call a method in each case.  `[self peripheralPoweredOn];`, `[self peripheralPoweredOff];`, and `[self peripheralUnsupported];`.

That way, not only do you fix the scope problem, but you are making it much easier for other things to drive the state of the peripheral beyond just the switch/case processing.

Comment: that still does not work though, the button does not change to green until I actually click it and leave the view, then I see it turn green for about 1/10th second before it leaves the view

Comment: Try calling `setNeedsDisplay` after changing the background color.

Comment: still does not work, the button remains its original colour until I press it and then it turns green for 1/10th of a second while the app exits that view

Comment: @MattDouhan Set a breakpoint on the button's -setBackgroundColor: and see who is reverting it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. My guess is that your outlet is not connected.

Try adding an NSLog statement inside the call:

```
switch (peripheral.state) {
  case CBManagerStatePoweredOn:
    NSLog(@"Powered on");
    [peripheral startAdvertising:_beaconPeripheralData];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      //-------------------------------------------------
      //Add the line below
      NSLog("_adminPageExitBtn = %@", _adminPageExitBtn);
      //-------------------------------------------------
      _adminPageExitBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    });
    break;
```

...

If that displays nil, you need to connect the outlet in Interface Builder.

Comment: looks ok, 2017-05-04 22:47:24.296989 NWMobileTill[580:91086] _adminPageExitBtn in main queue = <UIButton: 0x13fe4e820; frame = (182 646; 50 50); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tintColor = UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 1 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x17023a7a0>>

Comment: OP was describing a compiler error, not a runtime error.

Comment: @bbum, if you follow the comments, the OP says "That removes the error messages but the button don't change colour but the debug shows me that CASE is hit – Matt Douhan 6 hours ago ". So once he got past the compiler error, he had a new runtime error. That's what I was responding to.

Comment: @DuncanC. Missed that. Thanks.